# WPF checkbox in menu item and classic theme

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple WPF window:

```
<Window x:Class="InvertedColorTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="ABC">
                <CheckBox>Menu1</CheckBox>
                <MenuItem Header="Blabla"></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
</Window>
```

When you open the menu and move the mouse over the entries to highlight them it looks like in the pics below.

If I switch to the windows classic theme on Win7 (and on windows server systems) the "blabla" menu entry's text is getting inverted, but the checkbox text is not getting inverted.

Does anyone have an idea how to get around it? I am using dotnet 3.5

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by getting interveted? I don't see any difference.

Comment: Well if you would move the mouse over "blabla", it changes its text foreground color. I'm looking for a way to have the same on the checkbox labels. But I only want to correct this for the classic themes, so I can't just stupidly switch the color to white, because it would be hardly visible in the normal themes

Comment: You can create a style and apply it on the checkbox

Comment: And how to create a style, which applies ONLY to the classic theme?

Comment: Good question. I am sure with research and test/try you could achieve this. And then if you have a problem ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply a style to your combo and set the text color to [SystemColors.ActiveCaptionTextBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.activecaptiontextbrush%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). This will contain an appropriate color for each theme.

Comment: Thx, this is working. I used a style trigger

           `<Menu.Resources><Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Style.Triggers><Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"><Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionTextBrush}"></Setter></Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers></Style></Menu.Resources>`